# Transform a dataframe based on its datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dataframe:

```
date  = ['2014-02-03 23:00:00','2015-02-03 23:30:00','2015-02-04 00:00:00','2016-02-04 01:30:00'] 
value = [33.24  , 31.71  , 34.39  , 34.49  ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':value,'index':date})
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['index'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df.drop(['index'],axis=1,inplace=True)
print(df.head())

                     value
index                     
2014-02-03 23:00:00  33.24
2015-02-03 23:30:00  31.71
2015-02-04 00:00:00  34.39
2016-02-04 01:30:00  34.49
```

I would like to "pivot" efficiently the dataframe so has to have the following result:

```
                      2014   2015  2016
index                     
2014-02-03 23:00:00  33.24
2015-02-03 23:30:00         31.71
2015-02-04 00:00:00         34.39
2016-02-04 01:30:00                34.49
```

or even better 'collapsing' the previous one:

```
               2014   2015  2016
index                     
0             33.24  31.71  34.39
1                    34.39
```

I basically want to create a column per year. Any idea on how to do that efficiently?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
pd.pivot(df.index,df.index.year, df.value)

index                 2014   2015   2016
index                                   
2014-02-03 23:00:00  33.24    NaN    NaN
2015-02-03 23:30:00    NaN  31.71    NaN
2015-02-04 00:00:00    NaN  34.39    NaN
2016-02-04 01:30:00    NaN    NaN  34.49

# If you want blank strings instead of `NaN`:
# pd.pivot(df.index,df.index.year, df.value).fillna('')

# index                 2014   2015   2016
# index                                   
# 2014-02-03 23:00:00  33.24              
# 2015-02-03 23:30:00         31.71       
# 2015-02-04 00:00:00         34.39       
# 2016-02-04 01:30:00                34.49
```

Regarding your edit, to "colapse" this, you could use `np.sort` and create a new dataframe if order doesn't matter. Not sure if it will be the most efficient way to do it though.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(pd.pivot(df.index,df.index.year, df.value),0)).dropna(how='all')

       0      1      2
0  33.24  31.71  34.49
1    NaN  34.39    NaN
```

Comment: thanks! is it possible to basically 'collapse' the dataframe to get rid of most of the NaN values and obtain smth like                                                                      index     2014   2015   2016
index                                   
0           33.24   31.71    34.39
1            NaN    34.39    NaN

Comment: Sorry, can't tell what you mean without the line breaks in comments. Can you post your desired output in your question as an edit? As far as getting rid of the `NaN`s, is `fillna` not enough?